# Simulating a click through Windows API using C++ doesn't seem to work

Tags: winapi, click, sendmessage, findwindow

so I have been trying to simulate a click on my file explorer window to get back from my open folder to the previous directory. Straight forward. So I used SpyXX to know the window's names, so I can simulate this click.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

HWND hwnd = FindWindowA("CabinetWClass", "SpyXX");
if(!hwnd) {
    std::cout << "Error: Cannot find window!" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Success! Window found!" << std::endl;
}

HWND hwnd2 = FindWindowExA(hwnd, NULL, "WorkerW", "");
if(!hwnd2) {
    std::cout << "Error: Cannot find child window!" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Success! Child window found!" << std::endl;
}

HWND hwnd3 = FindWindowExA(hwnd2, NULL, "ReBarWindow32", "");
if(!hwnd3) {
    std::cout << "Error: Cannot find child window!" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Success! Child window found!" << std::endl;
}

HWND hwnd4 = FindWindowExA(hwnd3, NULL, "UpBand", "");
if(!hwnd4) {
    std::cout << "Error: Cannot find child window!" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Success! Child window found!" << std::endl;
}

HWND hwnd5 = FindWindowExA(hwnd4, NULL, "ToolbarWindow32", "Nach-oben-Symbolleiste");
if(!hwnd5) {
    std::cout << "Error: Cannot find child window!" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Success! Child window found!" << std::endl;
}

SendMessageA(hwnd5, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);


return 1;
}
```

And my output shows that the window has been found:

```
  Success! Window found!
  Success! Child window found!
  Success! Child window found!
  Success! Child window found!
  Success! Child window found!
```

However the SendMessageA command doesn't do anything. The file explorer window doesn't change, meaning the 'back' button has not been pressed. Why is that? What am I doing wrong? I also used the SendMessageW and SendMessage commands to no avail.

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Hacking windows that are not yours may or not work. The Shell has some API that can be used. Not sure what you're exactly trying to do so I can't be sure you could use it. Otherwise you could use UI Automation which was made exactly for that kind of purpose (UI manipulation, clicking on buttons, etc.): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you could try the following code:

```
    SendMessage(hwnd5, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));
    SendMessage(hwnd5, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));
```

Comment: Do you realize that you *"- MSFT"* folks have gained yourself a reputation consistently low credibility? This is no exception with respect to quality. Please see what a *real* Microsoft engineer has to say: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).